# elasticsearch-py search queries substantially slower than curl equivalent

Tags: python, http, elasticsearch, apache-zeppelin, elasticsearch-py

In a Zeppelin notebook, running the following query with elasticsearch-py 5x

```
es = Elasticsearch(["es-host:9200"])
es.search(index="some_index", 
          doc_type="some_type", 
          body={"query": {"term": {"day": "2018_02_04"}}}
)
```

Takes 28 minutes to return.

From the same notebook, using curl to run:

```
curl -XGET 'http://es-host:9200/some_index/some_type/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{"query": {"term": {"day": "2018_02_04"}}}
'
```

returns basically instantly.

Why is the python library performance so poor, and what can be done to make that fast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand *why* this works, but if I add a `filter_path` to the query, it returns as quickly as the raw curl:

```
es = Elasticsearch(["es-host:9200"])
results = es.search(index="some_index", 
      doc_type="some_type", 
      filter_path=['hits.hits._id'],
      body={"query": {"term": {"day": "2018_02_04"}}}
)
```

If anyone has an explanation for this behavior, I'd appreciate that.

Comment: if adding `filter_path` helps then it could be cause by the deserialization cost - if you have huge documents the `json.loads` call we do on every response to decode the body could take up significant amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

this is not anything I have ever seen, judging based on this question I would guess that there is something wrong with your environment.

Comment: Other queries run in the expected time, specifically get() and mget()

Comment: I've posted an answer. Perhaps you have some further insights?